# Netbeans IDE Display Issue on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, netbeans, centos

My CentOS 7.9 with GNOME Desktop installed.
Netbeans 17.0 installed while the Left nav area display not good.
The screenshots as below.
Any help is appreciated.
[image: Screenshot-from-2023-05-01-13-02-25.png]

And the pop-up window menu-list also the same issue.
[image: Screenshot-from-2023-05-01-13-28-11.png]

and my monitor setting as this,
[image: Screenshot-from-2023-05-01-13-03-05.png]

Comment: And I also tried to change the Display Scale back to 100%, It is still the same issue.